# iOS App works fine with Simulator but Crashes with a real iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, ios-simulator

I know there are already similar problems on StackOverflow, but mine is a little different. So when I launch my app on the simulator, it works just fine, however, when I launch it on a device, it loads everything and launches the app but as soon as it does that, both my Xcode and the app on my phone crash.

I have no code to post as my Xcode crashes but if you know why this is happening or any code that may be useful to you, please let me know.

Comment: When Xcode crashes, do you get a crash report, and if so, what does it say?   Also, use breakpoints (e.g. in AppDelegate `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and the first VC's `-viewDidLoad`) to figure out how far you get before the crash - this may give you a hint as to what is causing the problem

Comment: If you have a project that reliably crashing Xcode when launching on a device, send it to Apple in a bug report. Xcode crashing is their bug. Help them by telling them about it so they can fix it.

Comment: @RichTolley My Xcode quits, so I don't think I can get a crash report. But if there is a way to get one, please tell me

Comment: @AmavGUPTA - Normally you get a pop up asking if you want to send a crash report when Xcode crashes. Strange if you aren't getting one

Answer (score 1):

I think you should follow the orders to figure out what the problem is:

1、Make sure your device type and iOS Version is right. Some newer apis do may cause crash on old iOS version. If your device's iOS version is not the same as the version of your simulator, maybe it's the reason.

2、If you're using iPhone 5 or iPhone 5c. That means your device does not support 64 bit calculation. Check it out.

3、Add Global Exception from exception panel. Switch to exception panel -> click plus button on the left bottom of the panel -> Choose one or more global Breakpoint you want to add. Then you should get where is wrong before it crash.

Comment: Added a global breakpoint, it gets called twice on the AppDelegate and then both the programs crash.

Comment: @ArnavGUPTA Thy to add another breakpoint. Is there any log printed?